# What computable pseudo-ordinals are there with initial segment $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)$?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, order-theory, foundations, recursive-ordinals

The notion of a “computable pseudo-ordinal”, i.e. a computable linear order with no hyperarithmetical descending chains, is an old one going back to Stephen Kleene.  Joe Harrison wrote the [definitive paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1968-131-02/S0002-9947-1968-0244049-7/S0002-9947-1968-0244049-7.pdf) on them in 1968, showing that any such linear order is either well-ordered or has order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta)+\alpha$ for some computable ordinal $\alpha$, where $\eta$ is the order type of the rationals.

As a result, any computable linear order with an initial segment of order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)$ cannot be without hyperarithmetical descending chains.  But my question is, does there exist a computable linear order with an initial segment of order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)$ and no *computable* descending chains?  If there’s more than one, what are all the possible order types of such a linear order?

Comment: The first sentence of your second paragraph is wrong: remember that $1+\eta+1$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $1+\eta$, and so a Harrison order **does** have an initial segment of type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)$.

Comment: In particular, $\eta+1+\eta\cong\eta$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hmm, then I think I should reformulate my question in some way.  What I really want the initial segment to be is a path through $O^*$, the pseudo-ordinal nonstandard extension of Kleene’s $O$ obtained by intersecting all hyperarithmetical sets satisfying the defining conditions of Kleene’s $O$.  Tell me this: does a path through $O^*$ have any properties characterizing it that other linear orders of order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)$ do not?  Maybe being $\Sigma^1_1$-complete?